# LINQ query in EF7 with subquery does not return data

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am using MVC6 EF7 and have the below code. The LINQ query is giving error Evaluation timedout when I run in debug mode and if I simple run it the query does not display any data on the scree.
I tried without the subquery, the complete data is returned and I also tried making the subquery as the main query, that also returns data. But once I make it as a subquery, then it does not return data. What am i missing? Does EF7 not support Contains? Is there any other way to do it? I don't want to have a variable with the inner query and then use that, I want one combined query.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

using NavMember;

namespace NavMember.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/VendorsAPI")]
    public class VendorsAPIController : Controller
    {
        private TestNavMembershipContext _context;

            public class testlist
        {
            public int MVE_VEID;
            public string VE_NAME;
            public string VE_ADDR1;
        }
        public VendorsAPIController(TestNavMembershipContext  context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        // GET: api/VendorsAPI
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<testlist> GetVendors()
        {

            IQueryable<testlist> query = from t1 in _context.Vendors
                                         let t2s = from t2 in _context.VendorMemberResNM
                                                   where t2.MVMR_MMID.Value == 237244
                                                   select t2.MVMR_VEID.Value
                                         where t2s.Contains(t1.MVE_VEID)
                                         select new testlist { MVE_VEID = t1.MVE_VEID, VE_NAME = t1.VE_NAME, VE_ADDR1 = t1.VE_ADDR1 };
            return query;

        }
```

Comment: Did u try invoke `query.ToList()`

Comment: I did just now, didn't help...it gave an error The multi-part identifier "t2.MVMR_VEID" could not be bound. So I tried removing .Value, so the multi-part identifier error is gone, but again no data.

Comment: I believe the t2.MVMR_VEID.Value (or t2.MVMR_VEID, tried both) is not getting matched up to t1.MVE_VEID due to some type issue, not sure what though, because data does match between these 2 fields.